# Value from DatePicker in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

Does anyone know how to get the Date and time values from a Datepicker in Silverlight?

Everywhere I look I find answers only for DateTimePicker which is not available for Silverlight. Can this be done without the use of the Event argument?

Answer (score 0):

Try the property `SelectedDate` from the DatePicker, it should return a `Nullable<DateTime>` value.

Comment: I did it using the DatePicker and TimePicker independently and wrapping them into one. Thanks anyways!